# send string argument to javascript

Tags: javascript, html

in google i'm didn't find answer for my question.

I have submit who send arguments from form html to javascript.
Integer arguments i send successful but string and date i cant send ...
How i can do this? 
Thanks

HTML :

```
<div style="width:5%; float:right;">
    <div id="b-container">
        <div class="photo" data-title="Edit"> 
            <a href="javascript:PopUpShow5({{ item.main_id }}, {{ item.id }}, {{ item.description }}, {{ item.data_date }}, {{ item.end_date }}, {{ item.priority }}, {{ item.status }})">
                <input type="image" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/edit.png" border="0" width="17" height="17" />
            </a>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width:5%; float:right;">
    <div id="b-container">
        <div class="photo" data-title="Edit">
            <a href="javascript:PopUpShow5({{ item.main_id }}, {{ item.id }}, {{ item.description }}, {{ item.data_date }}, {{ item.end_date }}, {{ item.priority }}, {{ item.status }})">
                <input type="image" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/edit.png" border="0" width="17" height="17" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVA_SCRIPT :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#popup5").hide();
    PopUpHide5();
});

function PopUpShow5(main_id, id, description, data_date, end_date, priority, status) {
    $("#popup5").show();
    document.getElementById('id_get_post_pk').value = main_id;
    document.getElementById('id_get_post_id').value = id;
    alert(document.getElementById('id_get_post_description').value = description);
    alert(document.getElementById('id_get_post_start_date').value = data_date);
    alert(document.getElementById('id_get_post_end_date').value = end_date);
    document.getElementById('id_get_post_priority').value = priority;
    document.getElementById('id_get_post_status').value = status;

    $(document).keyup(function (ev) {
        if (ev.keyCode == 27) $("#popup5").hide();
    });
}

function PopUpHide5() {
    $("#popup5").hide();
}
```

Comment: use `<a href="PopUpShow5(&quot;{{ item.main_id }}&quot;, &quot;{{ item.id }}&quot;,` ...etc

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap string argument in `"`

```
javascript:PopUpShow5("{{ item.main_id }}")
```

And don't call JavaScript this way ;)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not help me

When i do this :   

<a href="javascript:PopUpShow5({{ item.main_id }}, {{ item.id }}, "{{ item.description }}", "{{ item.data_date }}", "{{ item.end_date }}", {{ item.priority }}, {{ item.status }})"><input type="image" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/edit.png" border="0" width="17" height="17" ></a>       
HTML did't find arguments in django